# Django pass URL parameter to custom FormMixin

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I have a page in my web app that can be accessed by the URL like this:
`http://localhost:8000/organizations/list_student/?school_id=19`

I'd like access to the `school_id` from the URL above for one of the form mixins, named `PhoneNumberMixin` (please see below). Could someone who's knowledgeable about Django tell me how I should pass that URL parameter into custom form mixin like `PhoneNumberMixin`? Thank you.

In `models.py`:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
```

In `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # There are more, but to save space, only relevant part is included
    url(r'^list_student/$', StudentListView.as_view(), name='list_student'),
)
```

In `views.py` for the page:

```
class StudentListView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = SchoolAddStudentForm
    template_name = 'organizations/list_student.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('organizations:list_student') + '?school_id=' + self.request.GET['school_id'] 

    def get_form(self, form_class):
        request = self.request
        return form_class(request, **self.get_form_kwargs())

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # add stuff to data to pass to HTML page here
        return data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        data = form.cleaned_data
        # save cleaned data to DB here
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

In `forms.py`,

```
# Note PhoneNumberFormMixin below. It is used to clean phone numbers 
# such duplicate checking against the existing numbers in the DB
class SchoolAddStudentForm(PhoneNumberFormMixin, forms.Form):
    phone_numbers = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs=form_attrs))

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SchoolAddStudentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['phone_numbers'].label = 'Step 1 (required): Add comma-separated list of phone numbers [E.g., 5856261234, 8613910912345]:'
```

In `mixins.py`:

```
class PhoneNumberFormMixin(object):
    """
    Custom form mixin for validating phone numbers
    """
    def clean_phone_numbers(self):
        data = self.data
        numbers = []

        sid = #!!!! this is where I'd like to access school_id from the URL
        qs = Student.objects.filter(school_id=sid)
        # do something with the qs
        return ','.join(numbers)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I have a full picture as you're missing views.py & urls.py. But generally, field cleaning methods should only check that an input is correctly formatted, and the actual application logic should be located in your view's form_valid() method. Form() methods don't have access to HTTP request information precisely because it is outside the scope of their functionality.

From your view, you can access the URL parameter with:

```
self.request.GET.get('school_id', None)
```

Read up on form_valid() -- this is where you should add code to modify an object + field values before it's saved, and / or create related objects if needed.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The reason I wanted to check whether `phone_number` already exists in the DB (in PhoneNumberMixin's `clean_phone_numbers`) is so that I can raise form.ValidationError to let user know. Is there a way to raise such error in the view? I think I have `views.py` pasted above. I'll add `urls.py` now. Thank you again.

Comment: Ah, in that case you can add `unique=True` to your model field, migrate the DB, and django should take care of the rest.

Comment: Got it! That might do the trick. I'll accept your answer if no one offers better, alternative solution in a couple of days. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my usecase I'm doing a search which displays a list of search results.

I ended up using this:

```
class SearchView(FormMixin, ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        # TODO implement filtering
        return qs

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        # use GET parameters as the data
        kwargs = super().get_form_kwargs()
        if self.request.method in ('GET'):
            kwargs.update({
                'data': self.request.GET,
            })

        return kwargs
```